# Why is get_current_user_id() returning 0 when used in woocommerce_login_redirect hook

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I was searching now for a while to find a solution for my problem, where the function `get_current_user_id()` returns 0 when hooked to `woocommerce_login_redirect`.
Right after the login-redirect there should always be an user-id, or am I getting s.th wrong here?

In my function.php file I have follwoing code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ffaces_register_customer' ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'ffaces_register_customer' );

function ffaces_register_customer( $user ) {

  $customerid = get_current_user_id();

  if ( $customerid == 0 ) {
    $redirection_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    return $redirection_url; 
    exit();
  }

  // more code working with $customerid

  return home_url("my-account/my-projects");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it the action hook to add_filter but it didn't help getting the userid. Could you specify how I should replace ```$customerid = get_current_user_id();```?

Comment: Finally I have answered then…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code (the first function argument is not the user, but the url redirection to be filtered). Try the following instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ffaces_register_customer', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'ffaces_register_customer', 10, 2 );
function ffaces_register_customer( $redirect, $user = '' ) {

    if( isset($user) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && $user->ID > 0 ) {
        return home_url("my-account/my-projects");
    } else {
        return get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    }

}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem! (a comma is missing between ```'ffaces_register_customer', 10,``` )

Comment: @DanielReiner Thanks, added the missing coma :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its set yet when this fires.

The hook passes the user object of the user that logged in try to change

`$customerid = get_current_user_id();`

to

`$customerid = $user->ID;`

Comment: I tried, but ```$user->ID;``` seems to be empty. I figured that I'm passing $user into my function, but I don't know where it should set the $user-object.